# Passing Parameter to another screen and show read only in another screen in PowerApps

Tags: combobox, parameter-passing, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I want passing parameter to another screen, clicking submit button while combo box data are selected and the combo box data will show read only in another screen in PowerApps

I have tried navigating one screen to another screen

Answer (score 0):

I am providing example solution below which should help you to resolve your issue. Make sure to change the control names and column names as per your application:

**First Screen**:

I have a combo box and a button control on it.

Formula on `OnSelect` of button control:

```
Navigate(Screen2, ScreenTransition.None, {lvComboBoxItems: ComboBox1.SelectedItems});
```

[image]

**Second Screen**:

I have a single "Label" control on this screen and `Text` property of label control is set to:

```
With(
    {
        vTxt: Concat(
            lvComboBoxItems,
            Value1 & ", "
        )
    },
    Left(
        vTxt,
        Len(vTxt) - 2
    )
)
```

Where `Value1` is the name of column from data source added to combo box control, you can replace it with your column name.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: QQ, why not just use a global variable?

Comment: If variable is going to be used on only one screen, it is better to create contextual/local variable instead of global variable. Check: [Understand variables in canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Thank for the answer, I tried your formula but it does not work, the label does not show in next screen.

Comment: Can you show us the `items` property of your combo box and which column are you trying to show in label? Do you get any error in the app? Did you change control and column names properly?

Comment: I wrongfully give column names, Now I got it, Millions Thank @GaneshSanap-MVP

Comment: "I want passing parameter to another screen" sounds to me like its more than one screen usage, idk, this solution seems overkill